# Values added to Settings.Default not persisting from one area

Tags: c#, winforms, properties.settings, user.config

**Problem: Items added to `Settings.Default` not persisting after page load.
Desired Functionality: Values added to `Settings.Default` saved and will load on next use**

I have a few different things that are stored in `Settings.Default` but one area isn't adding the values to the user.config file. I have a list of account numbers stored in `Settings.Default.accountList`. On load the form checks to see if there are values loaded in already and if not it loads in a list. That works fine. Later where the user can add a value it will do everything it is supposed to do except load to/stay in the user.config. The event handler looks like this:

```
accountNumber = FormOneMethods.NewAccount(accountNumber);
Settings.Default.accountList.Add(accountNumber);
Settings.Default.Save();
```

I added the .Save() later but that still didn't work. Why won't the values added persist?

Comment: What is the setting's scope, User or Application?

Comment: The scope is set to User

Comment: Perform a `Properties.Settings.Default.Upgrade() `

Comment: I put this line right under the code in my question but I'm still having the same issue.

Comment: Found the issue. I upgraded from VS 2013 to VS 2017 and it made a new folder for AppData and a new user.config. Everything is working properly now. Please put this into an answer so I can mark it as accepted. Thanks!